# PyKafka metadata in bytes instead of strings

Tags: python, apache-kafka, pykafka

I see an unusual behaviour with PyKafka, a client that I just recently began to use.

The error is the following:

```
Failed to connect newly created broker for b'4758e4ee1af6':9092
{0: <pykafka.broker.Broker at 0x7f319e19be10 (host=b'4758e4ee1af6',port=9092, id=0)>}
```

The source of the error is in this lines:

```
    self.client = KafkaClient(hosts=BROKER_ADDRESS, broker_version="0.10.1.0")
consumer = self.client.topics[bytes(self.input_topic,"UTF-8")].get_balanced_consumer(
        consumer_group=bytes(self.consumer_group,"UTF-8"),
        auto_commit_enable=True
    )
```

Debugging I saw that the client use the correct string IP to connect to the seed broker but when the list of brokers is retrieved, their IP are in binary and when PyKafka tries to connect again to create a consumer, these IPs obviously don't work.

Another problem, possibly connected, is that I need to convert topic names and consumer groups names to bytes by myself (like with other clients) but all the examples in the docs show the usage of strings.

Kafka broker version: 0.10.1.0
PyKafka version: 2.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was completely misled: that wasn't an IP but an hostname in base64 (generated by Docker).

Answer (score 2):

Check your brokers' `advertised.listeners` config - it defines the hostnames that will be sent to ZooKeeper and onward to pykafka clients during pykafka's `Cluster` initialization. It's possible that Docker is corrupting this information, so you'll want to override it using `advertised.listeners`. From the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/):

> Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use, if different than the `listeners` config property. In IaaS environments, this may need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds.

As for the bytes/string issue, the [latest development release](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/releases) of pykafka accepts strings *or* bytes for topic and consumer group names as a programmer convenience. For older versions, you will need to convert string arguments to bytes using a technique like this:

```
topic_name = str_topic_name.encode('ascii')
```